# how to access and save all data in iphone contacts

Tags: ios4

i need to save all the data in contacts like (phone no and mailID).my requirement is when click on contact name that contact data will be stored into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`Address Book`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FContactData%2FConceptual%2FAddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone%2FIntroduction.html&ei=MGjgTbe6LIborQeAtriZBg&usg=AFQjCNE1RzNEbaHazXJCJjapaIGe0_wS-w&sig2=mwPShh4YKYbaCjxIkpIoiw) and `Address Book UI` frameworks. You can either use the UI components directly which will take care of most things or directly access the address book and provide your own UI.